# How do you convert a list of strings to a list of floats using Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

If I have a list of strings:

```
['   3.2 4.5 7.8 9.2 4.3 4.7 5.2',
'   3.1 4.1 1.3 8.2 4.1 3.2 3.1',
'   3.1 4.2 5.7 3.2 4.1 3.0 1.9']
```

How can I convert it to a list of floats so my result looks something like this:

```
[[3.2, 4.5, 7.8, 9.3, 4.3, 4.7, 5.2],
[3.1, 4.1, 1.3, 8.2, 4.1, 3.2, 3.1],
[3.1, 4.2, 5.7, 3.2, 4.1, 3.0, 1.9]]
```

Comment: `print( [list(map(float, i.strip().split())) for i in l] )`

Comment: How did this list come to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below code:

```
numbers = ['   3.2 4.5 7.8 9.2 4.3 4.7 5.2',
'   3.1 4.1 1.3 8.2 4.1 3.2 3.1',
'   3.1 4.2 5.7 3.2 4.1 3.0 1.9']

print([[float(number) for number in number_list.split()] for number_list in numbers])
```

Comment: It would be more pythonic to use `map` when doing repeated operations on all elements in a list, such as `float()`

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
l = ['   3.2 4.5 7.8 9.2 4.3 4.7 5.2',
'   3.1 4.1 1.3 8.2 4.1 3.2 3.1',
'   3.1 4.2 5.7 3.2 4.1 3.0 1.9']

print( [map(float, i.strip().split()) for i in l] )
```

**Output:**

```
[[3.2, 4.5, 7.8, 9.2, 4.3, 4.7, 5.2], [3.1, 4.1, 1.3, 8.2, 4.1, 3.2, 3.1], [3.1, 4.2, 5.7, 3.2, 4.1, 3.0, 1.9]]
```

- `str.split()` to split element by space
- `map(float, 'YOURLIST')` to apply float on all elements.

Comment: You don't actually need the `list(...)` wrap

Comment: @dheiberg for OP you are correct (Py2.7) but you do in Py3 - `map()` returns an iterator, good to make a note.

Comment: @dheiberg.. Thanks i did not see python2.7 tag.